# How to execute dynamic math functions on client side using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, excel-formula

I have a web application. My task is to add ability to execute dynamic (or from server side loaded) a mathematical formulas like in Excel. 
Yes, I can use a JavaScript sandbox, but it is really unsafe and I don’t need so much functionality, just math (sum, multiply etc) and “if” phrase.
I hope you guys know the best way to implement math processor.

Regards Paul

Comment: Try [jison](http://zaach.github.io/jison/)

Comment: Please visit [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Zachary Kniebel, excuse me how this site is related to the above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own parser using  jison (http://zaach.github.io/jison/) or PEGjs (https://github.com/dmajda/pegjs).

As for the grammar specification, you should look at ECMA-376 (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) and MS-XLS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313154%28v=office.12%29.aspx).  Both have high-level descriptions of the formula language (with a pseudo-ABNF).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I chose jison

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expression parser included with math.js:

http://mathjs.org

Example usage:

```
math.eval('1.2 / (2.3 + 0.7)');   // 0.4
math.eval('5.08 cm in inch');     // 2 inch
math.eval('sin(45 deg) ^ 2');     // 0.5
math.eval('9 / 3 + 2i');          // 3 + 2i
math.eval('det([-1, 2; 3, 1])');  // -7
```

Comment: scripting capabilities like if statements, for loops, etc, is not yet supported but will be implemented in the future. That will be really cool...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
/* description: Parses end executes mathematical expressions with IF THEN ELSE statments. */
/* generated from http://zaach.github.io/jison/try/ */
/* The example IF(1>2) THEN 5 ELSE 1 */

/* lexical grammar */
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER'
"*"                   return '*'
"/"                   return '/'
"-"                   return '-'
"+"                   return '+'
"^"                   return '^'
"("                   return '('
")"                   return ')'
"<"                   return '<'
">"                   return '>'
"PI"                  return 'PI'
"E"                   return 'E'
"IF"                  return 'IF';
"THEN"                return 'THEN'
"ELSE"                return 'ELSE'
"=="                  return '=='
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
.                     return 'INVALID'

/lex

/* operator associations and precedence */

%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%left '^'
%left UMINUS
%left 'IF'
%left '<'
%left '>'
%left '=='

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */

expressions
    : e EOF
        {return $1;}
    ;

e
    : e '+' e
        {$$ = $1+$3;}
    | e '-' e
        {$$ = $1-$3;}
    | e '*' e
        {$$ = $1*$3;}
    | e '/' e
        {$$ = $1/$3;}
    | e '^' e
        {$$ = Math.pow($1, $3);}
    | '-' e %prec UMINUS
        {$$ = -$2;}
    | '(' e ')'
        {$$ = $2;}
    | NUMBER
        {$$ = Number(yytext);}
    | E
        {$$ = Math.E;}
    | PI
        {$$ = Math.PI;}
    | e '<' e
        {$$ = $1<$3;}   
    | e '>' e
        {$$ = $1>$3;}
    | e '==' e
        {$$ = $1==$3;}
    | IF '(' e ')' THEN e ELSE e
        {
            if($3 == true){
                $$ = $6;
            }
            else{
                $$ = $8;
            }           
        }
    ;
}
```

I'm not sure, it is the right approach, but it works for me. 
You can try it at http://zaach.github.io/jison/try/